# (WCF) .svc call returning the wrong mime type (works locally, not in production)

Tags: wcf

So I've been developing an app on my dev box for a while and it's time to put it in production.  My Service has a method which returns Xml.

This all works locally but when I copy the files over to the web server and try to connect to my WCS using a browser I get this message:

```
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
```

Why does it work locally?  Has my hosting provider setup something wrong?  Have I messed up some config or other?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the returned message? If it is text/html it usually indicates some error page. What does it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the production environment been properly set up?

If not, run ServiceModelReg.exe to register WCF http modules / mappings etc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx

--larsw

Comment: I assumed that this would just be on default.  I'll give this a shot. Thaanks

Comment: Don't assume, don't assume.  Apparently my hosting provider is back in the dark ages and I didn't read the small print.  Back to winhost I guess.